# c# mvc - how to return specific view from generic method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My service layer returns error code(s), and I have to return corresponding View. But with many possible error codes my controller methods will have big switch case. So I decided to inherit all controllers from some base controller which has this method:

```
 public IActionResult GetResponse<T>(ServiceResponse<T> serviceResponse)
    {
        switch (serviceResponse.Result)
        {
            case ServiceResult.Ok: return Ok(serviceResponse.ResponseObject);
            case ServiceResult.ValidationError: return BadRequest(serviceResponse.Messages);
            case ServiceResult.NoPermission: return Unauthorized(serviceResponse.Messages);
            case ServiceResult.NotFound: return BadRequest(serviceResponse.Messages);
            default: return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

Now, the problem is, input parameter for this method comes from service layer. Service layer returns me entity object. I need to somehow create ViewModel from this entity object. I can pass a parameter that indicates needed ViewModel type and make another switch block, but I don't think it's the best option. Is there any way to map entity to view model object in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add an error handing middleware such as below and hook it in the pipeline. Of course you're gonna need to modify this for your own story.

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context /* other dependencies */)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
            }
        }

        private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
        {
            var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // 500 if unexpected
            if (ex is CustomExceptionOne) code = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            if (ex is CustomExceptionTwo) code = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = ex.Message });
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
            return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
        }
    }
```

and in the startup configure method:

```
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
```

Comment: this would be great if I had exceptions, but I don't want to throw exceptions if I can handle errors without them

Comment: It doesn't need to be necessarily an exception. You may change the logic in Middleware to read the result and decide based on that rather than exception.